# Curry function with the first one as an async function isn't working

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

I'm trying to curry a function but when the first one is async it throws the error `function1(...) is not a function`, however if I pass the async function as the last one it works fine.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? and how to properly make a curry function that starts with a async function?

Thanks to anyone who take the time.

```js
//This one is throwing the error: function1(...) is not a function
async function function1(path) {
 const fetchedElement = await fetchElement(path);
//(...)
  return (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  };
}

function1('somepath.html')('my message');

//This one works fine, properly returning other function
function function2(path) {
  return async (msg) => {
    const fetchedElement = await fetchElement(path);
  //(...)
    console.log(msg);
  };
}
function2('somepath.html')('my message');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on when the async work needs to get done.  If you want the currying process to do the async work, then you can't invoke the currying function synchronously:

```
curryingFunction(paramA)(paramB)
                        ^ assumes curryingFunction is synchronous
```

Instead, use two statements by the caller, one to await the currying, the other to invoke...

```js
const fetch = path => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('fetched ' + path)
  resolve()
}, 1000));

async function curryingFunction(path) {
  const fetchedElement = await fetch(path);
  return message => {
    console.log(message);
  }
}

async function someCaller() {
  // await to get a curried function, then invoke it
  let curried = await curryingFunction('some_path');
  curried('some message');
}

someCaller()
```

On the other hand, you might not need to do the async work in order to get the curried function. You probably don't. In that case, you can make the currying function synchronous, but have it return an async function that does the async work.

As a result, you'll get to use the `fn()()` syntax that you're probably used to using...

```js
const fetch = path => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('fetched ' + path)
  resolve()
}, 1000));

function curryingFunction(path) {
  return async (message) => {
    const fetchedElement = await fetch(path);
    console.log(message);
  }
}

async function someCaller() {
  // here we can use the fn()() syntax that we're accustomed to
  await curryingFunction('some path')('some message')
}

someCaller()
```

Comment: This looks  workable, so I'll follow this approach with the async wraper as a caller. Tks a lot for your time

Comment: Just one addendum, to use the second aproach in my case I had to add parentheses to wrap the await call like this (await myCurryFunc('some path'))('some message'), then it works

Answer (score 1):

As the first function is `async` You need to `await` it first, then call the second parameter.

```js
//This one is throwing the error: function1(...) is not a function
async function function1(path) {
 const fetchedElement = await Promise.resolve(1);
//(...)
  return (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  };
}

(async () => {
try {
 (await function1('somepath.html'))('my message');
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
})()
```